# TypeScript Ghostscript import changed to gs_

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, ghostscript

Okay so a bit of a weird one, I have a cloud function running in the Google Cloud environment, written on my local machine in TypeScript which is using a Ghostscript reference i've put in the package.json as the following:

```
"gs": "https://github.com/sina-masnadi/node-gs/tarball/master",
```

Imported into my functions file like:

```
import gs from "gs";
```

With my TypeScript function looks like this:

```
await new Promise((res, rej) => {
    gs()
        .batch()
        .nopause()
        ...follows on from this
```

However when I deploy my functions with `firebase deploy --only functions` the compiler then puts together the `.js` file and uploads that (as you'd expect). Only in the `.js` funciton it's uploading, it's changing the references to the Ghostscript import to the following:

```
const gs_1 = require("gs");
```

And then the function code to:

```
yield new Promise((res, rej) => {
    gs_1.default()
        .batch()
        .nopause()
        ...follows on from this
```

When this function is then ran in the cloud, I get the following error printed:

```
TypeError: gs_1.default is not a function
```

Does anyone know why it's changing the name over, is it a reserved name possibly?

**UPDATE & FIX**
Changing the import for the ghostscript library to:

```
const gs = require("gs")
```

has fixed the issue thanks to help from @Nicholas Tower

Comment: The renaming that happens during compile time should be harmless. Are you sure that ghostscript has a default export, as opposed to a named export?

Comment: Good point, I switched up the import to `const gs = require("gs")` and that's solved it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am creating a Community Wiki answer to have an answer available for future reference to similar issues. According to the comments by Nicholas Tower, the solution to this issue was to refactor the import of the gs library from:

```
import gs from "gs";
```

To:

```
const gs = require("gs")
```

For further information, there is a documentation [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies) dealing with Firebase functions dependency handling.